# div background with fixed width

Tags: html, css, width, fixed

I'm looking for a way to give a div a background with a fixed width.
In particular I want the div to have a 5 pixel one-colored background (no percentages, no gradient) and the rest of the div being transparent. In this case I don't want to use a border!

Comment: Show us some effort, what have you tried ? Have you try googling that topic ? Quite sure there is solutions out there. We are not gonna make your work ! We just will help you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)You can use a pseudo-element and then style that.  Make it 5px wide and 100% height of the div to make sure it covers the whole lot.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1j4uko9/).

```
.bg {
    height: 100px;
}

.bg:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Worked with some customization, thanks for the help.